# How to mimic FireFox NET tab in C# / ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I'd like to create a web page where you can enter your domain name and have it fetch it and show you all the resources, their download times, etc -- similar to FireFox's NET tab.

Here's the page which I'd like emulate: http://tools.pingdom.com/

Now, I know this is a complex feature, but I'd like to hear general ideas. I know I could easily fetch the HTML via a WebClient, but that's the easy part. I need to fetch and time all the resources too, and not all at the same time. I want to mimic a browser. So, I thought about using something like System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser, but that will only really give me the page load time.

Anyone have any thoughts / tips?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) you can easily find which external resources are referenced from an HTML page.

This won't tell you exactly when they would be loaded by the browser, and also won't help you with dynamically loaded resources, but is a good start.

I'm afraid the only way to be sure is to instantiate an entire browser. You could use a plug in for the [Fiddler HTTP debugging proxy](http://www.fiddler2.com) to intercept requests from the WebBrowser control to determine which resources are actually loaded in this case.